# When was the quantization of spin discovered?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When was the fact that a spin could only have values $S = n/2$? I cannot find any source that says when.

Answer (score 2):

The experiment of Stern and Gerlach showed that the spin of atomic silver was 1/2.  This experiment was "simplified" by Phipps and Taylor to hydrogen atoms so as to eliminate any possible ambiguities on the spin-1/2 nature of the electron.